# Robot interaction language

Tags: speech-processing

Is there any well documented robot interaction language? I would imagine something like taking a user's speech in English, parsing it using some natural language processing like NLTK or Stanford NLP and then building a new sentence understandable by the robot. Does something like this already exists?

I recently found ROILA http://roila.org/language-guide/ but it seems like it is a whole different language and not just a reformulation of sentences using English words with less grammatical complexity.

Comment: There is now a stackexchange site for constructed languages here: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This does exist (or will, both eventually and inevitably).  The most relevant project to what you are talking about is [Eugene](http://www.princetonai.com/bot/) who recently [sort of passed the Turing test](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/technology/jamiebartlett/100013858/no-eugene-didnt-pass-the-turing-test-but-he-will-soon/).

Update: hopefully non-rotting link with up-to-date information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Goostman

Comment: I've added the now-available wikipedia article, since I can't seem to find copies of the first 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

Speech recognition is a pretty vast problem, if you are simply wanting to command a robot using your voice, a lot of ROS users use [Pocket Sphinx](http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx). You'll have to teach the program all the words, sentences or phrases you want it to recognize, but there are built-in tools that make this easy. It's also straight forward to teach it multiple phrases that mean the same thing, for example: come here, get over here, heel boy, etc. There is a nice example of how to use it in the *ROS by Example* book if you can get your hands on a copy.

If you're not using ROS, Pocket Sphinx is actually independent of ROS, that link just points to the ROS wrapper, I've never used it outside of ROS.

Comment: Thanks but speech recognition is not my problem now, I am using the Google unofficial API and it works quite well.